# <? echo __FILE__ . '>' . __LINE__ . '<hr>'; # ==> with strange output

Tags: php

If I use this php code I get really strange output (for me):

```
<? echo __FILE__ . '>' . __LINE__ . '<hr>';
```

Result in a web browser:

```
./sl5/echo_colored.functions.php' . __LINE__ . '
```

`phpinfo()` shows the following:

```
PHP Version 5.3.14<br>
...<br>
cgi.check_shebang_line  0   0<br>
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0<br>
zend_codetracing.trace_source_lines On  On<br>
```

Any suggestion for fix or workaround this?

Comment: Well, it looks like you don't have [`short_open_tag` enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).  Use `<?php` instead of `<?`  If you view the browser page source, I expect you'll see your full PHP code there, which was never executed as PHP and sent straight down to the browser.

Comment: ...or maybe that's not it if you are indeed getting the output of `__FILE__` in there.  Does your code look _exactly_ like you posted? The output looks like there may be a missing quote causing `__LINE__` to act as a string.

Comment: No, its not a  <?php or <? problem. Yes look exactly as posted. __FILE__ is replaced correctly (as you could see). Therfore its strange for me.

Answer (score 1):

`>` is a special char, just use `&gt;` instead.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. look exactly as posted. FILE is replaced correctly (as you could see). Therfore its strange for me.